# holonomy and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was trying to prove the following statement which relates the holonomy and curvature.

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ assume it has two smooth vector fields $V,W$ such that $[V,W] = 0$ (therefore the induced flow commute). Assume that we parallel transport along the flow line as follows:(1) first we transport along flow for vector field $V$ for $\epsilon$ time, (2)then along flow for vector field $W$ for $\epsilon$ time , (3) then along $-V$ for $\epsilon$ time (4) finally for $-W$  for $\epsilon$ time.

Since the flow commute, it will come back to the original point (denote this point $p$). Therefore it's an element in the homology group base at that point, denoting this parallel transport $P_\gamma$. I want to show:

$$P_\gamma = Id +\epsilon^2 R(V,W) + O(\epsilon^2)$$

Where $R(V|_p,W|_p) \in End(T_pM)$ be the curvature tensor after eating two vector fields $V$ and $W$.

---

I have no idea how to prove it. If possible we may write everything in the coordinate?